# Bootstrap editable does'nt follow PHP created table `while`

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, x-editable

I'm using `Bootstrap Editable` to get "Inline editing" in a PHP generated table.
My problem is that i'n only getting the first line in printed table to get "Editable". When i press the first table row, it's all works. But when i press the link of second table row, it´s just a link. It does'nt show up any Javascript.
What am i missing? The `HTML`looks fine?! And the "server-side" PHP can't be involved. Is it, the main JS of "Bootstrap Editable"?

**HTML/PHP**

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><a href='#' id='element_ant' data-name='element_ant' data-type='text' data-pk='".$row['id']."' data-url='php/edit_scanned_elements.php' data-title='Anteckning..'>".$row['element_ant']."</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
```

**HTML debugger**

```
<tr><td><span id='objekt_nr'>23047-3</span></td><td><span id='element_nr'>104</span></td><td><span id='element_scanned_by'>Rosa, </span></td><td><span id='element_scanned_where'>R.Avf- </span></td><td><span id='element_scanned_when'>2015-01-20 04:13:32</span></td><td><a href='#' id='element_ant' data-name='element_ant' data-type='text' data-pk='3190' data-url='php/edit_scanned_elements.php' data-title='Anteckning..'>test1</a></td></tr>

</tr><tr><td><span id='objekt_nr'>23047-3</span></td><td><span id='element_nr'>113</span></td><td><span id='element_scanned_by'>Rosa, </span></td><td><span id='element_scanned_where'>R.Avf- </span></td><td><span id='element_scanned_when'>2015-01-20 04:13:29</span></td><td><a href='#' id='element_ant' data-name='element_ant' data-type='text' data-pk='3189' data-url='php/edit_scanned_elements.php' data-title='Anteckning..'>test</a></td></tr>
```

**Custom JS**

```
$(document).ready( function () {  
    $('#element_ant').editable({
        title : 'Enter comments'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate different IDs for elements by your php code.
You can use `$row['id']` for this.

Comment: But how? My PHP "Backend-Script" is fetching "data-PK" and there is unique id, for "Mysql Update". The Custom JS is "tagetting" `#element_ant`. If i change that id on each php generated row, How can the JS know when to alert? I guess you need to explain deeper?

Comment: Use css class for "tagetting"